# Argument of type '{ period: any; prices: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MAInput'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, technical-indicator

I want to use `technicalindicators` in my Angular app written in TypeScript, but don't know how to import and use it?

What I want to do is calculating SMA(Simple Moving Averages) of an array.

EDIT:

I have installed `technicalindicators` module using `npm i --save technicalindicators` command. Then I imported it like this:

```
import {sma} from 'technicalindicators';
```

Then I tried to use it like this:

```
var prices = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15];
var period = 10;

  doSMA(period , prices){
    console.log('sma result is:' , sma({period, prices}));
  }
```

But I get this error message:

> Argument of type '{ period: any; prices: any; }' is not assignable
>   to parameter of type 'MAInput'

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use it no problem.. From the source, they have the TS interfaces already.

[technicalindicators GitHub](https://github.com/anandanand84/technicalindicators/blob/master/dist/StockData.d.ts)

You just need to `npm install --save technicalindicators`

And to use it, you would import in your angular project the same as any other, have you tried it ?

for example :

```
import { StockData } from 'technicalindicators';
```

EDIT as per your error:

Following the documentation, the `sma` method requires 3 params.

eg:

```
sma({period : 10, values : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], reversedInput : true});
```

From what I can see, it looks like you want to use a SMA.calcultate .

```
SMA.calculate({period : 10, values : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]});
```

The error is quite clear though.

[TechnicalIndicators Documentation](https://github.com/anandanand84/technicalindicators#readme)

Here is a working example: [DEMO](https://runkit.com/anandaravindan/sma)

Comment: Thanks Pogrindis! But It seems my downloaded module doesn't have `src` folder. I want to calculate `MACD` for a numerical array but don't know how to do it?

Comment: I am looking for `src` folder because it seems `.ts` files are inside of it.

Comment: You won't need to worry about which one as the node_module will pick up which to use based on the module iteself. Unless you are going to modify the library itself ?

Comment: @Hasani did you ever get this fixed ? You just need to create a `MAInput` and pass through .. No ?